# How moment.js works with declination minutes and hours?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Tell me pls, have a number, for example **1440** and i need get or minute, or minutes, or hour or hours. What can I do? I do:

```
var getTimeouts = function (timeouts) {
    var timeout = +timeouts,
        timeoutValue = "";

    if (timeout > 0) {
        if (timeout % 60 == 0) {
            if (timeout == 60) {
                // timeoutValue = '1 hour';
            } else {
                // timeoutValue = '... hours';
            }
        }  else {
            if (timeout == 1) {
                // timeoutValue = '1 minute';
            } else {
                // timeoutValue = '... minutes';
            }
        }
    }

    return timeoutValue;
};

console.log(getTimeouts(1440)); // 24 hours
```

Question: how with [momont.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/) I can parse a number and get minute/minutes/hour/hours?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: It sounds like he just wants to use the correct plural form of the words "hour" and "minute," depending on the value of a number, expressed in minutes, given to him.

Comment: Yes,  dodexahedron is rights! Help pls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only sort of do this with momentjs.

`moment.duration().humanize()` will give you a string that loosely represents the duration.

```
moment.duration(60,"minute").humanize(); //= an hour
moment.duration(1,"minute").humanize();  //= a minute
moment.duration(5,"minute").humanize();  //= 5 minutes
moment.duration(55,"minute").humanize(); //= an hour       <-!!!
```

Depending on you needs, it might be good enough.

But if you need something that is actually accurate, use the [HumanizeDuration plugin](https://github.com/EvanHahn/HumanizeDuration.js).

```
humanizeDuration(3000)      // "3 seconds"
humanizeDuration(2015)      // "2.25 seconds"
humanizeDuration(97320000)  // "1 day, 3 hours, 2 minutes"
```

And if you don't need the extra language support it comes with, just manually delete those parts of the plugin.

**Edit:**

In case I misunderstood and you just need a number representing the hours, minutes, seconds, etc.

You can use `moment.duration().as('something')`.

```
var getTimeouts = function (timeouts) {
    var timeout = +timeouts,
        timeoutValue = "";

    if (timeout > 0) {
        if (timeout % 60 == 0) {
            if (timeout == 60) {
                timeoutValue = '1 hour';
            } else {
                timeoutValue = parseInt(
                moment.duration(timeouts, 'minutes').as('hours'), 10) + ' hours';
            }
        } else {
            if (timeout == 1) {
                timeoutValue = '1 minute';
            } else {
                timeoutValue = parseInt(
                moment.duration(timeouts, 'minutes').as('minute'), 10) + ' minutes';
            }
        }
    }

    return timeoutValue;
};
```

Working copy: http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/c90v76s9/3/

You could of course add the logic to make it give you stuff like "1  hour, 2 minutes"